# Is it possible with stochastic gradient descent for the error to increase?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, objective-functions

As simple as that. Is there any scenario where the error might *increase*, if only by a tiny amount, when using SGD (no momentum)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Not only that, but error is highly noisy, prone to big spikes and sometimes quite long period of increase before decrease again or stabilize. Often it's even impossible to understand error plot without passing it through smoothing filter, so noisy it is. Specific depend on the problem of cause. It's not only for SGD but for any optimizer.